# Building: --disable-statusline is unrecognized option

Tags: statusline, compile-vim

I want to improve [Gentoo ebuild](https://github.com/gentoo/gentoo/blob/2fa11adb8132a51c8b179d747460a64cee469048/app-editors/vim/vim-8.2.0814-r100.ebuild).

I tried `:helpgrep statusline`.

In the future, how can I get all possible build flags about features in `:version`?

Comment: Why would you want to disable support for the statusline? How would this improve Gentoo ebuild?

Comment: If I recall correctly, statusline is not an option, that can be disabled at compile time. So what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @filbranden I want to disable features that I do not use, for faster compilation, more security, faster startup, less ram usage. Of course I want to disable statusline not for all, but by introducing USE flag.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I trying to build Vim with features that I use, for performance. If we cannot disable `+statusline` - this is strange that we see it in `:version`.

Comment: The minimal amount of time savings from faster compilation and speedup will be vastly less than the amount of time you've already spent on this :-)

Answer (score 2):

Vim features are not completely orthogonal, so not all of them are available as individual flags to enable/disable.

If you want a minimal build of Vim, you can use `--with-features=tiny`. I believe this will disable the statusline feature as well, together with many other features disabled to produce a minimal build.

This setting is already available in the Gentoo ebuild as a `minimal` use flag.

Comment: The features are defined in `feature.h` by the way; in this case, it's named `FEAT_STL_OPT`, and it's set with `#ifdef FEAT_NORMAL #define FEAT_STL_OPT`. It's never defined/set anywhere else. If the OP cares deeply about this, then they can probably just modify the `feature.h` file to remove this and that will work. No guarantees though; warranty voided, etc. There's just no option to set this directly because the number of people who want a "fully featured Vim but without a statusline" are probably very few.